# Conditional Facecolor/No Facecolor

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am trying to create a `sns.scatter` plot with, depended on a condition eather both open or closed faced markers.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[2,2,3,1,5],'C':['Y','Y','N','N','Y']}) 
fig = sns.scatterplot(
    data=df, x="A", y="B" ,s=100, edgecolor ='black', facecolors = 'none')
```

In the example I would like to create a scatter plot where all the markers where `C` is `N` have no facecolor and all the markers where `C` is `Y` do have a facecolor. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe just `ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="A", y="B", hue="C",  s=100, edgecolor='black', palette={'Y': 'none', 'N': 'skyblue'})`?  Also note that `sns.scatterplot` is an axes level function and returns an `ax`.  Calling the return value `fig` can lead to a lot of confusion when later adjustments are made via matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot call the scatterplot function twice and plot them separately on the same axis:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[2,2,3,1,5],'C':['Y','Y','N','N','Y']})
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(6,4))

fc = {"Y":"none","N":"blue"}
for i in fc.keys():
    sns.scatterplot(data=df[df['C']==i], x="A", y="B" ,s=100, edgecolor ='black',
                facecolors=fc[i],label = i,ax=ax)
```

[image]